# How to define the nodes allowed to execute a job depending on the parameters of the job?

Tags: jenkins

On jenkins, one can set the nodes allowed to execute a job, based on static labels.

How to define the nodes allowed to execute a job depending on the parameters of the job ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the node or label to run the build on using special parameters from [Jenkins NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) or compute a slaves label expression with Groovy code using [Groovy Label Assignment plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Label+Assignment+plugin).
Both options will override static labels if any.

Comment: [Jenkins NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) is exactly what I was looking for. The description of the plugin is not so well wrote, I saw it already without understanding the objective ... thks